# JQM: How to catch click events in each button-lik(area) from an img sprite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In Jquery Mobile, let's say I have 2 buttons-like in an img sprite. I need the buttons to on the img sprite. custom buttons on img sprite:

```
 ---------
| button1 |
 ---------
| button2 |
 ---------
```

1.) How would I catch click events in each button from the img sprite?
+1 for an elegant approach
2.) or any other way to deal with this?

P.S: I'm sorry, i cannot find an existing api or plugin for this.. and this is a new feature for me

Answer (score 1):

Use SomeThing like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
    alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this could be good already, however I hope there is a better interface that utilizes this pattern =]